# How to configure MSMQ Task to send message to different MSMQ based on variable in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, msmq

I have a column inside the database that contains messages. These messages need to go to a different `MSMQ` based on the message ID.

How do I configure the `MSMQ` Task inside SSIS to take a different connection string based on the message `ID`? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one way is to write a Script Task which will take the connection string as a parameter and send it out to the specified queue. Use this task inside a For Each Loop to get the connection string for each message and send them out one at a time.